# Migrating to Durable Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a non-durable pipeline of three Azure Http Trigger Functions. They pass along a custom json graph in a sequence.

I have started to migrate this to Durable Functions (using the sample as a basis) and it appears that I can just pass the json graph around as a string without using Task<HttpResponseMessage> etc.

Is this the best way with Durable Functions. Could I still keep each function as a HttpTrigger in order to have the flexibility of calling the whole pipeline as Durable but each individual as an HttpTrigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each function needs to have an ActivityTrigger to work with Durable Functions - and we do not support having multiple triggers for a single function. To keep both options (HTTP Triggered or as part of a Durable orchestration) you would likely need to factor out the common code into a shared method that each function can invoke.